# MP3 Music Player - AS3, XML and ListBoxes

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, listbox, mp3, audio-player

I have compiled different codes through various sites on how to create my own MP3 player for my site. The buttons are working great. The sliders, visualizers and timers are all working fine.

I just want the listbox so that it pulls the data directly from the XML file (playlist.xml). I guess I could potentially use a function similar to the play button but have it so that each new .addItem is whatever it is that I have in my xml.

Here are the codes for the xml and the listbox:

XML::

```
    var mySongList:XMLList;    
    var myTotal:Number;    
    var s:Sound;    

var c:SoundChannel;    
var currentSong:Number=0;    
var lastPosition:Number=0;    
var dragging:Boolean=false;    
var boundingBox:Rectangle=new Rectangle(0,0,175,0); 
var pos:int = 0;

var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();    
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("/Music_Test/playlist.xml"));    
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);  


function processXML(e:Event):void { 
    var myXML:XML=new XML(e.target.data); 
    mySongList=myXML.song; 
    myTotal=mySongList.length(); 
    myXMLLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML); 
    myXMLLoader=null; 
    playSong(0); 
}    

function playSong(mySong:Number):void { 
    var myTitle=mySongList[mySong].@songName; 
    var myArtist=mySongList[mySong].@artist; 
    var myURL=mySongList[mySong].@url; 
    //displays the song title and artis in the text fields
    title_txt.text=myTitle; 
    artist_txt.text=myArtist; 

    if (c) { 
        c.stop(); 
        c=null; 
    }

    s = new Sound(); 
    s.load(new URLRequest(myURL)); 
    c=s.play(lastPosition); 
    c.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, nextSong); 
    visTimer.start();
    c.stop();
}
```

And here is the code for the listbox:

```
listbox.addItem({label:"Song1"});
listbox.addItem({label:"Song2"});

listbox.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playList);

function playList(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    c.stop();
    c = s.play(0);
    tB3();
    txtTotalTime.text = timeCalculation(s.length);
    txtCurrentTime.text = timeCalculation (c.position);
    myTimer.start();
    seekSlider.minimum = 0;
    seekSlider.maximum = Math.floor(s.length);
    Volume();

}
```

I have other codes in there for other functions like the seekSliders, song timers, and volume.

Can somebody explain to me how I would go about pulling info from playlist.xml so that it will directly send to the listbox?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Put your xml format like this

```
<song>
     <songtitle>Some title here</songtitle>
     <url> song name or url</url>
     <songtime> can add more data like above under each song</songtime>//example
</song> //copy above and add info for each song and save it as xml


var i:unit;
var songurl:URLRequest;
```

Load your xml file:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "link to your xml file here";
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest (XML_URL);
myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener(event.COMPELETE, xmlLoaded);
```

now you have to put them in you list

```
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{
myXML= XML(myLoader.data);
var firstsong:String = myXML..song.songtitle[0];
var firsturl:String = myXML..song.url[0];
songURL = new URLRequest(firsturl);

 for each (var song:XML in myXML..song){
 i++;
 var songtitle:String = song.songtitle.toString();
 var songtime:String = song.songtime.toString();
 var songurl:String = song.url.toString();
 list.addItem({label:i+". "+songtitle"-"+songtime, urlstring: songurl});
 }
```

now you just have to load the song url and play it and make a function so when you click on each item it changes the urlstring and load, and play it.

you may put as much as song info in your xml file and it should load them to your list.

Comment: Hello I tried to use what you had put in but it just created some more errors. Can you clarify the coding for the list.additem? I know that the label is just what is needed to label the list. How do I go about in pulling the list from my existing xml? Do I change the xmlLoader so that it's pull in a URLString? Sorry, I'm not too familiar in certain aspects about xml and AS3

Comment: Hi, I think this is what you need, this is very nice/detail tutorial  youtube.com/watch?v=x7YRwFoZEt0